# Add Insertion Sort's costs in lstlisting

Tags: listings, algorithms, sorting

I'm trying to add the costs for each part of the Insertion Sort (that are marked in blue in the picture below)
[image]
At the moment the code I wrote is this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=`']
    InsertionSort(A)
        n = A.length
        for j=2 to n
        `\begin{equation*}
            n-1
                \begin{cases}
                    key = A[j] \\
                    i = j-1;\\
                    while(i>0) and (A[i] > key)\\
                        A[i+1] = A[i]\\
                        i = i-1 \\
                    A[i+1] = key;
                \end{cases}
        \end{equation*}'
\end{lstlisting}
```

I know that this snippet won't work properly. I hope someone can help me\

**Edit**: Probably `lstlisting` is not the right environment to use.
I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so every piece of advice is well accepted

**Edit2**: I also tried with `clrscode3e`, but I don't know how to go on

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clrscode3e}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{InsertionSort}(A)$}
\li $n \gets \attrib{A}{length}$
\li     \For $j \gets 2$ \To $n$
\li     \Do
            $\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li         $i \gets j-1$
\li         \While $(i > 0)$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li             \Do
                    $A[i + 1] = A[i]$
\li                 $i \gets i-1$
                \End
\li         $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
        \End
\end{codebox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to use braces that span several lines, you could use `tikzmark`s for this. I have to admit, that the code looks a bit overloaded, but I did not find any other possibility to insert code at the beginning of each line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[%
    escapeinside=`', 
    basicstyle=\linespread{1.2}\selectfont,
    morekeywords={InsertionSort},
    keywordstyle=\underbar
]
`\tikzmark{l1}'InsertionSort(A)
`\tikzmark{l2}'n = A.length 
`\tikzmark{l3}'    for j=2 to n
`\tikzmark{l4}'    key = A[j] 
`\tikzmark{l5}'        i = j-1
`\tikzmark{l6}'        while(i>0) and (A[i] > key)
`\tikzmark{l7}'            A[i+1] = A[i]
`\tikzmark{l8}'            i = i-1 
`\tikzmark{l9}'        A[i+1] = key;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
    span/.style={cyan, decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}},
    cost/.style={cyan, anchor=base, align=left, text width=75pt},
]
    \draw[span] ([xshift=3em, yshift=.9em]pic cs:l5) -- ([xshift=3em]pic cs:l9) node[pos=.5,left] {$n-1$};
    \draw[span] ([xshift=5.5em, yshift=.9em]pic cs:l7) -- ([xshift=5.5em]pic cs:l8) node[pos=.5,left] {$t_j$};
    
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l1) (n1) {$C_0$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l2) (n2) {$C_1$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l3) (n3) {$C_2 \cdot n$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l4) (n4) {$C_3 \cdot (n - 1)$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l5) (n5) {$C_4 \cdot (n - 1)$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l6) (n6) {$C_5 \cdot \sum^n_{j=2} (t_j + 1)$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l7) (n7) {$C_6 \cdot \sum^n_{j=2} t_j$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l8) (n8) {$C_7 \cdot \sum^n_{j=2} t_j$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:l9) (n9) {$C_8 \cdot (n - 1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: I just discoverey that the `tikzmark` package already comes with some support for the `listings` package. Hence, the above could also be achieved as follows. It is then even possible to easily include some lines connecting the nodes to the right with the end of each line of code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    basicstyle=\linespread{1.2}\selectfont,
    morekeywords={InsertionSort},
    keywordstyle=\underbar,
    name=code,
]
InsertionSort(A)
n = A.length 
    for j=2 to n
    key = A[j] 
        i = j-1
        while(i>0) and (A[i] > key)
            A[i+1] = A[i]
            i = i-1 
        A[i+1] = key;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
    span/.style={cyan, decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}},
    cost/.style={cyan, anchor=base, align=left, text width=75pt},
]
    \draw[span] ([xshift=3em, yshift=.9em]pic cs:line-code-5-start) -- ([xshift=3em]pic cs:line-code-9-start) node[pos=.5,left] {$n-1$};
    \draw[span] ([xshift=5.5em, yshift=.9em]pic cs:line-code-7-start) -- ([xshift=5.5em]pic cs:line-code-8-start) node[pos=.5,left] {$t_j$};
    
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-1-start) (n1) {$C_0$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-2-start) (n2) {$C_1$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-3-start) (n3) {$C_2 \cdot n$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-4-start) (n4) {$C_3 \cdot (n - 1)$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-5-start) (n5) {$C_4 \cdot (n - 1)$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-6-start) (n6) {$C_5 \cdot \sum^n_{j=2} (t_j + 1)$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-7-start) (n7) {$C_6 \cdot \sum^n_{j=2} t_j$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-8-start) (n8) {$C_7 \cdot \sum^n_{j=2} t_j$};
    \node[cost] at ([xshift={\textwidth-75pt}]pic cs:line-code-9-start) (n9) {$C_8 \cdot (n - 1)$};
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,9} 
        \draw[dashed, cyan] ([xshift=5pt]pic cs:line-code-\i-end) -- (n\i.base west);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what I was looking for. I know it's a bit overloaded, but in my notes these costs make sense :P